# I can't send the results of a query made in PHP to JSON in jquery. I think the results of the query are too long

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

My code works when the results of my query are smaller. When I add fields that have long (string) content, then my code stops working. So my code works for short query results, but stops working when the results are long strings.

I have tried altering the query itself. If the fields are small (varchar 255 or less), then my code works, but when the fields are TEXT and are therefore long, then my code doesn't work.

```
<?php
    require_once 'x_apricot/conn2019.php';    

    $Data_List= array();

    $query = "
    SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, DateCreated, BrunchDate
    FROM wobrunch 
    WHERE BrunchDate = '2019-09-08 00:00:00' 
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC";        

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();


    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

However, if I add ONE field to the query. In this case `LongLived` (the field) which is a very long TEXT field. Then it stops working. I expect the output to be this: `echo json_encode($results)` and it's blank (there are no results at all.

```
$query = "
        SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, DateCreated, BrunchDate, LongLived
        FROM wobrunch 
        WHERE BrunchDate = '2019-09-08 00:00:00' 
        ORDER BY DateCreated DESC";
```

Comment: define "a very long TEXT ". In numbers

Comment: can you select just that column?

Comment: Just an observation ... There's no need to keep a connection script in the htdocs folder (or a subfolder thereof), nor does it need a need a .php extension. As to your actual problem - sorry, no idea.

Comment: How do I definite a very long TEXT in numbers? Do you want me to send the file of the content? Or count the words?

Comment: It seems like it will work just fine with fields (columns) that have one word in them, but when I add a field that is text (maybe 10-20 words in that field), then the whole thing stops working.

Comment: UPDATE: I've been playing around with the query all morning. I found this: IF I exclude one record out of the result, then it works. But if I include this one record, then it stops working (returns nothing). I looked through every field in this one record. I could not find anything unusual. And when I run the query within PHPMyAdmin, it works just fine. It's only when I run it within my own code.
It's a mystery!

Comment: Why are you echoing the result of `json_encode()` without testing for success? Capture the return value, test it, use [error functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to determine problems if necessary.